# VBA to mysql connection

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I have added the Microsoft Active DataX Object to the Excel file.
I have also downloaded the mySQL ODBC Connector.

Below is the Code for Connection in VBA:

```
Sub ConnectDB2()
    Dim rs
    Dim Conn
    Dim cmdString

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    Conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};SERVER=52.74.22.123;DATABASE=sads;USERNAME=shridas;PASSWORD={KJH3232C8fed5AD!87367$Bds};"
    Conn.Open
    cmdString = "Select * from order"
    Set rs = Conn.Execute(cmdString)
    Conn.Close
End Sub
```

But I am getting an error:
'-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation error , Unspecified error.

Can you Please help me with this.

Comment: Hint for the future: You shouldn't include login and passwords in your posts in public forum

Comment: and what makes you think I have given the right username and password and its not a random generated one..

Comment: Which row of code gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `USERNAME` parameter in this line:

```
    Conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};SERVER=52.74.22.123;DATABASE=sads;USERNAME=shridas;PASSWORD={KJH3232C8fed5AD!87367$Bds};"
```

to just `USER`

```
Conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};SERVER=52.74.22.123;DATABASE=sads;USER=shridas;PASSWORD={KJH3232C8fed5AD!87367$Bds};"
```

On my machine, I've also got to use different ODBC name:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}
```